# flex box inside a flex box with scroll overflow?

Tags: html, css

I've looked at the similar questions that came up from this title, but they're not quite the same issue I'm having.

https://jsfiddle.net/kx4q1ut8/1/

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100vh;background:gray;">
  <div style="background:red;  width:100vw;min-height:80px;">Header</div>  <!-- Header -->
  <div style="background:green;width:100vw;flex-grow:1;display:flex;flex-direction:row"> <!-- outer body container -->

    <div style="background:blue;  width:140px;height:100%;"></div> <!-- side bar -->
    <div style="background:yellow;height:100%;flex-grow:1;display:flex;flex-direction:column"> <!-- inner body container -->
      <div style="background:gray;width:100%;height:200px;"> <!-- filter panel -->
      </div>
      <div style="background:cyan;width:100%;flex-grow:1;overflow:scroll"> <!-- table panel -->
        want this content scrollable if beyond bottom of page

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

All the areas are fixed sizes except for the cyan area. I need that area expandable to match the rest of the window height. What I also need is for that area to have scrollable content but can't seem to work that part out completely. If you fill the area with enough text it'll get a scrollbar but I think that container is expanding beyond the bottom of the page because I can't fully scroll to see the end of the off-screen content. The layout is for a web application.

[image]

Comment: You can try by giving a max-height to cyan area. Something like max-height: calc(100% - 280px); as per your design.

Comment: Played around with that for a bit, unfortunately it hasn't had the desired affect.

Comment: Actually, correction. That did help resolve it. I didn't have spaces around the minus sign. The one time spacing matters in css....

Comment: add margin:0 to body